# Convert Webflux API stream response to List<Object>

Tags: reactive-programming, webflux

I am very new to reactive programming. I am consuming a webflux API which is returning stream response ( application/stream+json ). My task is to call the API and convert response to List. My code snippet for calling API

```
ClientResponse res  =  webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri("uri")    
               .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)
                .header("Accept","*/*").exchange().block();
```

The API response is

```
{
 "name" : "Andrew"
  ....
}
{
 "name" : "Bob"
  .....
}
```

I am trying out few examples like

```
Flux<String> flux = res.bodyToFlux(String.class);
List<String>> list1 = flux.collectList().block;
```

But this returns list1 with just a single String of the entire response but my requirement is List of multiple string corresponding to each { } in API response. Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `block()` you switch to imperative code. So, here

```
ClientResponse res  =  webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri("uri")    
               .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)
                .header("Accept","*/*").exchange().block();
```

you are breaking the reactive stream. You should change it to:

```java
return webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri("uri")    
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)             
            .header("Accept","*/*")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
            .collectList()
            .block();
```

Answer (score 0):

Flux to List without block()

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri("uri")    
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)             
            .header("Accept","*/*")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
            .collectList().subscribe(list::addAll);
```